# Using html inside function that sends an email

Tags: html, wordpress, email

I'm using a function in wordpress to send emails to users when a role is changed. I need to insert some html into the `$message` but it just comes out as text in the email. How can I use html tags inside the message correctly?

```
    function user_role_update( $user_id, $new_role ) {
$site_url = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
$user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );

if (user_can( $user_id, 'capability' ) ) {

    $to = $user_info->user_email;
    $subject = "Role changed: ".$site_url."";
    $message = "Hello " .$user_info->display_name . " your role has changed on     ".$site_url.", congratulations you are now an " . $new_role;
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);

} elseif (user_can( $user_id, 'capability' ) ) {

// etc...

}

}
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'user_role_update', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a content-type to the headers of your mail message denoting that it is to be formatted in HTML:

```
$to = $user_info->user_email;
$subject = "Role changed: ".$site_url."";
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
$message = "Hello " .$user_info->display_name . " your role has changed on     ".$site_url.", congratulations you are now an " . $new_role;
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```